# Changing Height in CSS with Variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm trying to make the height of my DIV's respond to the width of the window. The code:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var mathW = parseInt(w);
var divHeight = mathW*0.16;
document.getElementById('demoDiv').style.height = divHeight;
```

With the CSS being:

```
#demoDiv {
   margin: auto;
   background-color: red;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px; //just to start with SOMETHING
}
```

Obviously I'm having trouble with that! I've played around with it and definitely can change the height if I just use regular integers, but even using parseInt('divHeight') did nothing for me!

Comment: `document.getElementById('demoDiv').style.height = divHeight+"px";
`

Comment: I don't know how in javascript, but in jQuery, you need to use [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Use CSS not JS for this.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you want to use Javascript for a task that is so easy to solve using only CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calucalting the height in a correct way. But in order to set the height you need to add dimension to the value (say `px`).

You dont need to do `parseInt` as `window.innerWidth` is a property with typeof `number`.

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var divHeight = mathW*0.16;
document.getElementById('demoDiv').style.height = divHeight+"px";
```

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot!! Thank you I'll mark this as answered when it lets me.

Comment: Why would anyone do this with JS at all?

Comment: @connexo with what you will do this then?

Comment: `height: 16vw;`, see my answer below. It's what comes to mind first when presented with this task.

Comment: And how does that answers OPs question? He is asking why his code is not working... There are always multiple way you can take to reach a destination and most of the times multiple ways could be correct :)

Comment: Well in this case it's totally obvious that a JS based solution is clearly inferior in every way thinkable.

Answer (score 0):

What stops you from applying a pure CSS solution?

```
#demoDiv {
  height: 16vw;
}
```

Requires no Javascript, is much shorter and performs faster, and no need to apply any resize handler when window size changes.